# How to shuffle list of pointers in C++?

Tags: c++, boost, stl

How to shuffle stl list of pointers in C++ ?
I have stl vector of pointers on class Player and I shuffle like

```
std::random_shuffle(players.begin(), players.end());
```

Is there already algorithm for shuffle list without requiring Random Access or I need to convert list to vector => shuffle => back to list ? Is there more elegant solution ?

Comment: Is there some reason you need to use a list?

Comment: Consider that *lists are **almost always** much less efficient than vectors*, even in domains where they are historically seen as superior.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I need lot of inserting operatins and list is better choice, also I've inherited that code and have hard deadline so I din't want to gamble now

Comment: You may ask yourself why you're using `std::list` in the first place. The situations where `std::list` shines is when 1) you require iterators to always remain valid (to store them for instance, but pointers to `std::deque` elements or indices in a vector are alternatives to consider), 2) you want constant time splicing. If you need neither 1 or 2, use something else (this means either `deque`, `vector` or `[multi]set`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The random shuffle algorithm swaps a specific element with a randomly chosen one. It would be very inefficient to repeatedly traverse the list to get the elements (namely it would be an `O(n^2)` operation).

That's why it would be better (faster) to copy your list to an array once, do a random shuffle and possibly restore the list. That would be `3*n` traversals, which is still `O(n)`.

Comment: Great for very long list where complexity starts to play a role. But for short list (like playlists) the constant factors may play a larger role. Save complexity theory for the correct place (this is not it) we do not expect to need to scale indefinitely.

Comment: @LokiAstari For a short list the constant factors don't matter also - it's fast no matter how you do it. So, IMHO, you'd better be prepared for a large playlist where speed matters, than optimize for short lists where it doesn't matter and fail at large ones.

Comment: I would say code for the common case first then optimize only if necessary. Not code for the exception then optimize for the common case (premature optimization is the route of all evil `Knuth`). The point is const factors matter more when the list is short. But that is not the point. Don;t blindly apply what you learned at college. You need to know the correct time to apply them. This is not that situation (until you can prove that playlist get long enough to matter). Even if the playlist was 100,000 I doubt the time to do a random shuffle is noticeable to the human eye.

Comment: You'd be wrong. Just benchmark it and you'll see. A random shuffle with 100,000 elements copied to a vector will be fast. A random shuffle implementation that traverses the list for every swap will be **much** slower. But you don't have to take my word for it, just try it.

Comment: I am not saying it will be faster. I am saying you are using the wrong technique for solving the problem (even if you got to the correct solution). I am saying complexity theory is irrelevant to the situation. Also I don't believe it is noticeable (I tried) unless you are running on 1980 hardware.

Answer (score 1):

`std::random_shuffle` needs a random Iterator. Vector supports this whereas a List does not. How about `std::deque`, its like a sort of Vector and sort of List.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was interesting. So, I tried writing something and finally came up with this.

```
    //---------- sample List initialization ------
    list<string> lst;
    lst.push_back("A");
    lst.push_back("B");
         ....
    lst.push_back("Y");
    lst.push_back("Z");

    #define LIST_SIZE 26
    //--------------------------------------------

    //------------- Shuffle Algorithm ------------
    unordered_multimap<int,string> mymap;
    int HashKeys[LIST_SIZE];
    srand((int)time(NULL) * (int)clock());

    for(int i = 0; i<LIST_SIZE; i++) // loop 'n' times
    {
        HashKeys[i] = rand(); // O(c) operation
    }

    for(int i = 0;lst.size() > 0; i++) // loop 'n' times
    {
         // O(n) operation ( varies from O(c) to O(n) according to the situations )
        mymap.insert(std::make_pair<int,string>(HashKeys[rand() % LIST_SIZE],lst.front()));
        lst.pop_front(); // O(c) operation
    }

    unordered_multimap<int,string>::iterator it;
    for(int i = 0; i < LIST_SIZE ;i++) // loop 'n' times
    {
        while(mymap.count(HashKeys[i]) > 0) // unpredictable
        {
            it = mymap.find(HashKeys[i]); // O(c) for single O(n) for multi
                    // ...USAGE...
            cout << it->second << endl;
                    lst.push_back(it->second);
                    //............
            mymap.erase(it); // O(c) operation
        }
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------
```

Time Complexity is O(n^2) if there are multiple values for same key in the hash map.
Otherwise the time complexity is O(n).
so everything depends on the function `(rand() % LIST_SIZE)`